# La « toute » vieille

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

Dans les paroles de [*Ces gens-là*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfwW76JzVQI), de Jacques Brel, (dont il est aussi question dans [ce fil de discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1230447&p=8009498#post8009498)) on trouve :

> Y a la moustache du père
>   Qui est mort d'une glissade
>   Et qui r'garde son troupeau
>   Bouffer la soupe froide
>   Et ça fait des grands flchss
>   Et puis y a **la toute vieille**
>   Qu'[en finit pas d'](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/finir/33820/locution?q=finir#172221)vibrer

Que signifie **la toute vieille** ? Je suis au fait que **vieille** en tant que nom féminin implique une vieille dame ou une mère.

En outre, les êtres humains ne m'apparaissent pas vibrer ? 
Prière d'expliquer la structure grammaticale de la phrase.

Comment: *Toute* à été ajouté pour obtenir le bon nombre de syllabes. C'est tout.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: oui, bien sûr, mais ici ça veut quand même dire « très ». Et elle est si vielle, qu'elle vibre (=tremble) sans cesse (elle n'en finit pas).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans [sa chanson](http://fr.lyrics-copy.com/jacques-brel/ces-gens-la.htm) Jacques Brel décrit avec ses mots de poète les divers membres d'une famille. La toute vieille c'est non seulement **la plus âgée de la famille**, mais elle est **très vieille**.  Les personnes âgées sont souvent atteintes de [tremblements](http://www.vulgaris-medical.com/encyclopedie-medicale/tremblements-generalites)<sup>1</sup>. Vibrer doit être pris ici comme synonyme de *trembler*, même si dans la vie courante les deux mots ne sont pas toujours interchangeables. Et elle tremble tout le temps : **elle n'en finit pas**.

Du point de vue de la grammaire, l'emploi de tout(e) ici est celui du 2. b. β. (épithète à valeur d'adverbe intensif) décrit dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout).

---

<sup>1</sup>   Le tremblement essentiel (dont on ne connaît pas la cause), que l'on appelait tremblement sénile (des personnes âgées) est une variété de tremblement qui touche entre 200 000 et 400 000 personnes en France.

Comment: _Toute vieille_ fait aussi penser à _tout jeune_ qui est plus employé, c'est plus que très vieux, c'est à l’extrême limite de la vieillesse.